# Using regex to extract particular text in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

[image: data input/table]

Would like to fetch the value for the key[Work Order Description:] and print it.

**Scripts Used:**

```
CREATE TABLE demo3 (id INT, log VARCHAR);
INSERT INTO demo3 (id, log) VALUES 
(1, 'Work order submitted on 12-03-2020
Work Order Description:Lights are not working
Work order status:Completed'),
(2, 'Work order submitted on 5-04-2020
Work order Priority:P3
Work Order Description:Electrical equipment issue
Work order status:Completed');
```

**Implemented Solution:**
select id, substr(log, regexp_instr(log, 'Work Order Description:') + 23, 300) as log from demo3;

**Implemented Solution Output:**

```
id log
1  Lights are not working Work order status:Completed
2  Electrical equipment issue Work order status:Completed
```

**Issue:**
Last lines are also attaching to the output. Instead I am looking to trim the output at the end of the line.

**Desired Output Required:**

```
1, Lights are not working
2, Electrical equipment issue
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` as in:

```sql
WITH data AS (
SELECT 2 AS id, 'Work order submitted on 5-04-2020
Work order Priority:P3
Work Order Description:Electrical equipment issue
Work order status:Completed' AS log
)

SELECT id, REGEXP_SUBSTR(log, 'Work Order Description:(.*)', 1, 1, 'e')
FROM data
```

Comment: **This works like a champ. Thank you @Felipe Hoffa**